# Find Roll and Column of Name with latest Date

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a table with three columns,
ID, Name and Date

[image]

then I create a userform with textbox ID and Name.

how could I display the Name of similar ID from the table with latest Date when I key in the ID in the userform? (similar ID will have different names, but I want to display the one with latest date in the table)

thanks in advance for all the help

coding for the textbox1

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
getdata
End Sub
```

coding for the getdata module

```
Sub getdata()

If IsNumeric(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value) Then
flag = False
i = 0
id = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
        flag = True
        For j = 2 To 3
            UserForm1.Controls("textbox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
        Next j
    End If

    i = i + 1

Loop

If flag = False Then
    For j = 2 To 3
        UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
    Next j
End If

Else
    ClearForm
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please provide more information about how your data is laid out and what your code looks like - and whether you want a VBA solution or a formula solution.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I need a vba solution, what I would like to create is a userform with two textbox, for example when I key in 1 for the ID textbox, the Name textbox will display Sam NOT John because date of Sam is the latest

Comment: **Please provide more information about how your data is laid out and what your code looks like**.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon so as the picture, it shows name cc when I type 1 in the textbox of ID, what i like is to display name aa instead of cc since its date is more recent

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: @ExcelHero not really...because when I type 1 in the ID textbox it shows ntg with your code, what i like to create is when I type 1 in the ID textbox it shows aa as the date is 7/6/15 which is more later

Comment: @ExcelHero the textbox for name and date display nothing

Comment: There has to be something small that is different there than here. Could you send me a small workbook that has this in it? I'm sure I could get it going right away. My email is daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88065/discussion-between-green-and-excel-hero).

Comment: I just sent the workbook back to you. It works well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you. This routine goes in your userform code module:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    TextBox2 = Evaluate("=INDEX(B2:B999,MATCH(MAX((IF(A2:A999=" & TextBox1 & _
                        ",1)*(C2:C999)),1),IF(A2:A999=" & TextBox1 & _
                        ",1)*(C2:C999),))")
End Sub
```

It assumes your data are in columns A, B, and C. It also assumes your data do not extend past row 999; if they do, then increase the 999's in the formula to what is appropriate.

TextBox1 is for the ID.
TextBox2 is for the Name.

Note that this code is placed in the `AfterUpdate` event procedure. This is different than your sample code. You used the Change event procedure. The difference is that Change fires on each keystroke while AfterUpdate fires only after the full text is confirmed for the textbox.

Note that you should still add error checking for the case where the ID is not numeric and also for the case where the numeric ID does not match. The code above is simply for demonstrating the technique to display the looked-up value. If you wish for me to flesh it out more, please let me know.

**UPDATE**

I went ahead and fleshed it out with the error checking:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    GetData
End Sub

Public Sub GetData()
    Dim v, w
    On Error Resume Next
    v = Evaluate("=INDEX(B2:B999,MATCH(MAX((IF(A2:A999=" & TextBox1 & _
                 ",1)*(C2:C999)),1),IF(A2:A999=" & TextBox1 & _
                 ",1)*(C2:C999),))")
    w = Evaluate("MAX((IF(A2:A999=" & TextBox1 & ",1)*(C2:C999)))")
    If IsArray(v) Or IsError(v) Then v = "ID not found.": w = ""
    TextBox2 = v
    TextBox3 = "": TextBox3 = CDate(w)
End Sub
```

***UPDATE 2***
In the fleshed out version directly above, I added support for the associated date in TextBox3.

Comment: I think yours displays the largest row, not the one with the largest date. So you would have sort the worksheet first.

Comment: @DickKusleika  Yep. Brain fart. It's updated and does the right thing now.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the whole range in when the userform opens, sort it, then find the first ID.

```
Private mvaData As Variant

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    Me.TextBox2.Text = vbNullString
    Me.TextBox3.Text = vbNullString
    GetData
End Sub

Public Sub GetData()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(mvaData, 1) To UBound(mvaData, 1)
        If mvaData(i, 1) = Val(Me.TextBox1.Text) Then
            Me.TextBox2.Text = mvaData(i, 2)
            Me.TextBox3.Text = mvaData(i, 3)
            Exit For 'stop after the first one - largest date
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lId As Long, sDesc As String, dtDate As Date

    'store the data in a variable when the forms opens
    mvaData = Sheet1.Range("A1:C5")

    'sort with larger dates on top
    For i = LBound(mvaData, 1) To UBound(mvaData, 1) - 1
        For j = i To UBound(mvaData, 1)
            If mvaData(i, 3) < mvaData(j, 3) Then
                lId = mvaData(j, 1)
                sDesc = mvaData(j, 2)
                dtDate = mvaData(j, 3)

                mvaData(j, 1) = mvaData(i, 1)
                mvaData(j, 2) = mvaData(i, 2)
                mvaData(j, 3) = mvaData(i, 3)

                mvaData(i, 1) = lId
                mvaData(i, 2) = sDesc
                mvaData(i, 3) = dtDate
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```